# Программа, для обработки двухмерных матриц, Язык - Паскаль

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, pascal, матрицы

Напишите программу, реализующую обработку двухмерных массивов. Дана матрица размера M x N. В каждом ее столбце найти количество элементов, больших среднего арифметического всех элементов этого столбца.
Моя попытка -

```
const
    M = 5;
    N = 4;
 
var
    a: array[1..M, 1..N] of byte;
    i, j: byte;
    sum: integer;
 
begin
    randomize;
 
    sum := 0;

    for i := 1 to N do begin
        for j := 1 to M do begin
            a[i,j] := random(10);
            write(a[i,j]:3);

            sum := sum + a[i,j]

        end;
        writeln
    end;
 
    writeln ('------------');
 
    writeln('sum = ', sum);
 
end.
```

Comment: так не вычисляете ни среднее, ни проводите сравнений с ним. просто сумму посчитали, да еще и не по столбцам, а просто сумму всего массива

Answer (score 1):

Ну давайте разбираться.

Столбцов `N`, значит, в циклах индексация неверная, должна быть `a[j, i]`

Сумму чего вы считаете? Для среднего арифметического по столбцу нужна сумма только этого столбца. Значит, нужно  `sum` обнулять внутри первого цикла, а в конце его считать среднее, и делать ещё один внутренний цикл, чтобы найти количество бОльших элементов

Comment: Здравствуйте, просто я почти нечего в этом не смыслю, я та понял дальше необходимо посчитать среднее, но уменя еще проблема с индекса за массивом...